# double tap of right command to right arrow

Tags: keyboard

I am coding on VSCode and it is pretty hard to press left and right arrows. I wanted to modify some keys. Double tapping right or left commands will trigger left or right arrows.

I've tried to do that on Karabiner. I wasn't able to do my own custom key settings (only importing from web?).

Is there any way that I can do it on VSCode setting?

Comment: By left/right arrow you mean the cursor keys? Don't know about VSCode specifically, but generally on macOS you can use Ctrl-B/Ctrl-F to move the cursor left/right.

Comment: Right. Wondering if I can set it to like double tapping `right command` key to move the cursor to the right?

Comment: How would you handle key repeat to move several characters at once?